# Is there a better way to handle file encoding in python?

Tags: python

I have some text files with different unknown encoding. Now I have to open a file as binary to detect the encoding first, and open it again with that encoding.

```
  bf = open(f, 'rb')
  code = chardet.detect(bf.read())['encoding']
  print(f + ' : ' + code)
  bf.close()
  with open(f, 'r', encoding=code) as source:
    texts = extractText(source.readlines())
  source.close()  
  with open(splitext(f)[0] + '_texts.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as dist:
    dist.write('\n\n'.join('\n'.join(x) for x in texts))
  dist.close()
```

So is there a better way handle this problem?

Comment: Where do those files come from?

Comment: Look at this link.
Might be useful to what you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263136/how-to-deal-with-unknown-encoding-when-scraping-webpages

Comment: @EricDuminil It is some files for different softwares. There is no way to guess the encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reopening and rereading the file, you could just decode the text you already read:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fileobj:
    binary = fileobj.read()
probable_encoding = chardet.detect(binary)['encoding']
text = binary.decode(probable_encoding)
```